# How to set columns in LaTeX Seminar slide?

Tags: errors, presentations

Even though I can use `beamer` to create presentation slide. But this time I only interested in using [`seminar.sty`](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/nonstd/seminar.pdf) to write a slide for presentation, but failed to create a columns-like page.

Here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass{seminar}

\begin{document}
\begin{slide}

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}
Hello, world!
\end{column}

\begin{column}
How are you?
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{slide}
\end{document}
```

But I got this:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment columns undefined.
```

I am interested in such a beautiful example, but I don't know the way to create.

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, `column` and `columns` are defined in `beamer` but not in `seminar`.

Comment: Change `seminar` to `beamer` and `slide` to `frame` and probably add an optional argument with the width to the `column` environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found `minipage` can do what `columns` do in beamer.

```
\begin{slide}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
  \mybullet{In Seminar slide documentclass, \yell{minipage} can do what             
\yell{coloumns} does in Beamer. }
  \mybullet{The current sheet where tearing happens is called \yell{Harris layer}.}
  \mybullet{Simulations is 2.5D: fields are 2D, particle motion is 3D.}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{fig/fig_intro} 
    \caption{Harris layer configuration.}
  \end{figure}
\end{minipage}

\mybullet{Seek the Lord diligently! The Lord will greatly bless you!}
\mybullet{At this, those who heard began to go away one at a time, the older ones first, until only Jesus was left, with the woman still standing there.- John 8:9}

\end{slide}
```

[image: Seminar minipage example]